# Easiest way to extend a Struct (PointF)

Tags: c#, point, bezier

We need to store one additional piece of information with a PointF (the t parameter of the location along a Bezier curve).

Since this data can not be easily recalculated, I want to store it with the PointF at the time that the point is calculated, for use in other routines.

We have hundreds of references to PointF, so I was hoping not to have to create a new replacement class, but "extend" the PointF struct with one additional property.

The client code would be something like:

```
PointF intersection = new PointF();
intersection.X = 3457.23;
intersection.Y = -277.738;
intersection.t = 0.744;
```

Is this (or anything like this) possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a property or field onto an existing class or struct you don't have the source for.  You will need to make your own new struct to carry additional data.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear... but exactly what I thought.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry PointF is a struct (as you already said that) so you can't Extend it.

You'll need to make your own type

Answer (score 2):

This is rather dirty but if the value of T will always be the same for a given PointF you could use extension methods to simlulate the get/set behaviour that properties offer. Assuming you are using C# 3.0 compiler you could do something like this.

```
public static class PointFExtensions
{
      private static Dictionary<PointF, float> _dict = new Dictionary<PointF, float>();

      public static void SetT(this PointF self, float t)
      {
         _dict.Add(self, t);
      }

      public static float GetT(this PointF self)
      {
        return _dict[self];
      }
}
```

Then you could use these methods like this:

```
PointF pf = new PointF(4.0F, 5.0F);
pf.SetT(42);
float t = pf.GetT();
```